# How do I add an azure_function_endpoint to an event grid subscription?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Does anyone know how I can add an azure function end point to an event grid subscription?

I am trying to create an event grid subscription with an azure function end point. I am unable to add my function id as I can't find the ID or what format it should be in the main.tf file.

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "vehicle-images" {
  name  = "defaultEventSubscription"
  scope = "${azurerm_resource_group.vehicle-images.id}"
  event_delivery_schema = "EventGridSchema"
  topic_name = "downloaded-images-topic-2"

   azure_function_endpoint {
    function_id = "${module.vehicle-images.id}/functions/BlobTriggerCSharp1"
  }
```

The main problem is the function id. I can't find any decent documentation on how to do this. I have tried the function URL which also didn't work.

Comment: Is the function you are trying to reference also defined in Terraform or already exists without Terraform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we   add an azure_function_endpoint to an event grid subscription with terraform, the `function_id` should be like `/subscriptions/<subId>/resourceGroups/<groupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<functionapp name>/functions/<function name>`.

[image]

For example

```
data "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                = ""
  resource_group_name = ""
} 

resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "vehicle-images" {
  name  = "defaultEventSubscription"
  scope = ""
  event_delivery_schema = "EventGridSchema"
  topic_name = "test"

   azure_function_endpoint {
    function_id = format( "%s/functions/%s",data.azurerm_function_app.example.id,"<function name>")
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but I tried it and nothing happened. It seems to run apply but no subscription created showing in the Azure portal

Comment: @Funky Could you please provide the output when you run apply?